# WPF populate listbox with sql server instances

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I use:

```
_dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
```

to populate a data table with sql server instances. In my forms app I use:

```
lbxInstance.ValueMember = "Name";
lbxInstance.DataSource = _dataTable;
```

to populate the `ListBox` and it works. I am trying to populate a list box in WPF using the same data table as above, but it is empty. I ck that the data table is not null so I seem to have the data. Here is what I am using:

```
ListBox x:Name="lbxInstance" SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="item"
```

and:

```
if (_dataTable != null)
{
    lbxInstance.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
    lbxInstance.DisplayMemberPath = "item";
    lbxInstance.ItemsSource = _dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

Any ideas on what needs to be done to make it work?

Comment: did you try creating your own `DataView`: `lbxInstance.ItemsSource = new DataView(_dataTable)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code snippet for WPF

```
if (_dataTable != null)
{
    lbxInstance.DataContext = _dataTable;
    lbxInstance.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
    lbxInstance.DisplayMemberPath = "item";
}
```

### In XAML

```
<ListBox Name="lbxInstance" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```